# CakePHP - two models on one page, can't get this->request->data automagic field population

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have two controllers: events and results. Events hasMany results, results belongsTo Events. I can save just fine, but when I go to edit, I can only get the information for the Event part of the form, to come in automagically.

I build the Results form info like this:

```
$option_number = 5;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $option_number; $i++) {
           echo $this->Form->select("Result.{$i}.object_id", $qual_options, array('empty' => false, 'class' => 'result-name'));
           echo $this->Form->hidden("Result.{$i}.id");
           echo $this->Form->hidden("Result.{$i}.type", array('value' => 'qual'));
           echo $this->Form->hidden("Result.{$i}.action", array('value' => 'add')); ?>
}
```

In the backend, when I'm doing this to get the automagic population:

```
if ($this->request->is('get')) {
            $this->request->data = $this->Event->findById($id);
}
```

It works just fine, but I can't figure out how to get it to show the Results. I've tried many things, most probable being:

```
$this->request->data['Result'] = $this->Result->findAllByEventId($id);
```

With that, I end up with a data structure like:

```
[Result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Result] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [object_id] => 1
                            [type] => qual
                            [action] => add
                            [amt] => 10
                            [event_id] => 1
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Result] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [object_id] => 2
                            [type] => qual
                            [action] => add
                            [amt] => 1
                            [event_id] => 1
                        )

                )         

            ... etc.

        )

)
```

Which definitely looks fishy, I just can't seem to manipulate it to work.

**UPDATE** I should have mentioned this; this is what my data looks like when I SAVE it, and I want to mimic this!

```
[Result] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [object_id] => 1
                [type] => qual
                [action] => add
                [amt] => 0
                [event_id] => 3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [object_id] => 1
                [type] => qual
                [action] => add
                [amt] => 1
                [event_id] => 3
            )
```

You can see that each numeric key after just has the information in it; instead, my numeric keys ALSO have an array INSIDE them name Result, and I have no idea how to make that go away properly! :} I could always loop through and build it in the format CakePHP wants, but I want to do it properly. And that single line above is what needs changing, but I have run out of ideas.

Comment: Tip: post your form (empty) and debug the $this->request->data array - the way it looks then you need to make your data and it will work and auto-populate correctly. I can never remember it either, but with this trick you always can find out.

Comment: Hi Mark, I realized after reading your comment that I should post the structure save() uses. I did that and made the question a bit clearer, I hope.

Comment: So you can just restructure the array using a single foreach loop.

Comment: For every part of this software in which I have to do this? And this is what CakePHP suggests I do? I find it hard to believe.

Answer (score 0):

What about just using `find('first')` against the event? Since it's hasMany, it will return the Result model in a single `[Result]` key with many numeric keys.

```
$this->request->data = $this->Event->find('first', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'Event.id' => $id
  ),
  'contain' => array(
    'Result'
  )
));
```

This will return something like:

```
array(
  'Event' => array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'event name'
  ),
  'Result' => array(
    0 => array(
      'id' => 1,
      ...
    ),
    1 => array(
      'id' => 2,
      ...
    )
  )
);
```

You could unset the Event key if you needed to.